# Modificar orden de productos con sortable

Tags: laravel, ajax, laravel-5, sortable

estoy utilizando sortable.js para coger y arrastrar filas y así cambiar su orden de muestra. Esto mismo que estoy haciendo ahora, lo hice hace una semana en el mismo proyecto pero ordenando los destacados y funcionaba perfecto, pero ahora no me guarda en la bd el cambio.

En la tabla he añadido una columna que se llama orderParafernalia, es por la columna que voy a ordenar.

En el controlador primero hago la consulta para mostrar los registros:

```
$productosClientes = Product::join('categories', 'products.categoria', '=', 'categories.id')
                     ->where('products.visiblePara', 3)
                     ->where('products.estado', 1)
                     ->where('categoria', 2)
                     ->orderBy('products.orderParafernalia', 'asc')
                     ->select('products.*', 'categories.name as nameCategoria')->get();
```

Luego en la vista los muestro con un foreach:

```
<div id="productosClientesPara">
    @foreach ($productosClientes as $item)
      <div class="card addCard" data-id="{{ $item->id }}">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-2">
             <img src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}" alt="" class="imgenTablePro22">
           </div>
           <div class="col-10">
           <div class="divTitle">{{ $item->name }}</div>
              <div class="cattitle">{{ $item->nameCategoria }}</div>
           </div>
           </div>
             <span class="pospoints"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></span>
           </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

El AJAX de sortable:

```
const productosClientesPara = document.getElementById('productosClientesPara');
    Sortable.create(productosClientesPara, {
        group: {
            name: "productosClientesPara"
        },
        animation: 150,
        easing: "cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22",
        handle: ".pospoints",
        store: {
            set: function (sortable) {
                let orderParafernalia = {};
                $('.card').each(function() {
                    orderParafernalia[$(this).data('id')] = $(this).index();
                });
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'orden-420/modificaOrdenParafernalia',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {orderParafernalia: orderParafernalia},
                    success: function(data){
                        toastr["success"]("Orden actualizado", "Mensaje")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

La ruta:

```
Route::post('mi-cuenta/orden-420/modificaOrdenParafernalia', 'adminController@modificaOrdenParafernalia')
```

Y en el controlador para hacer el UPDATE.

```
public function modificaOrdenParafernalia(Request $request)
    {
        foreach($request->get('orderParafernalia') as $id => $orderParafernalia) { 
            Product::find($id)->update(['orderParafernalia' => $orderParafernalia]);
            
        }
    }
```

Recibo el Toast y código 200 pero no hace el cambio, puedo mostrar de algún modo el error, me parece súper curioso, lo hice del mismo modo hace una semana.

Hay alguna forma de devolver el error por el que no guarda?? solo necesito saber eso.

Comment: Tu error puede radicar en que estás declarando `orderParafernalia` como un objeto y al final, como no lo conviertes a string, no se envía nada a tu controlador. Revisa que llegue la data a tu controlador. Además, no es necesario un objeto, con un array simple se puede lograr esa tarea

Comment: Hola @JonatanLavado probe a cambiar el `find` por `Product::where('id', $id)->update(['ordenP' => $order]);` y ahora funciona no lo entiendo, pero funciona

Comment: Tenías agregado el campo `orderParafernalia` a tu modelo Product?

Comment: Si correcto! lo tengo añadido en el modelo, la verdad que no entiendo nada